# Angular with @types/swiper

Tags: angular, typescript, types, swiper.js

I'm using `@types/swiper` in Angular 6 project and I'm getting an error (Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature) when trying to create a new instance of Swiper.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-swiper?file=src%2Fapp%2Fswiper%2Fswiper.component.ts)

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error on my local and while trying to do so, i first installed Swiper with 'npm i --save swiper' then Swiper types with 'npm install --save @types/swiper' and somehow, it uninstalled Swiper. I tried tsconfig and typings.d.ts modification also but nothing worked. Then i realized that Swiper is missing from my node_modules. Installed Swiper again and the error is gone :). Please check your node_modules one more time.

Comment: The problem occurs when I'm typing the variables and not related to Swiper, please check out the StackBlitz. 
btw, as of npm 5 modules are added as a dependency by default so the --save option is redundant (;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration of the `swiper` module in `@types/swiper` is wrong: the declaration says that the module has a named export `Swiper` of the `Swiper` class, but it actually has a default export of the class (or an export assignment depending on whether your bundler uses the CommonJS or the ES6 version: argh, stupid packaging).  I've submitted [a pull request to DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/29500) to attempt to fix the declaration.  If you use my modified declaration (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52503107) for the possible ways to do that), your code should compile successfully.

Comment: When I wrote this type definition I did not think that someone would possibly want to use the non-esm version.