# Extend typescript function into callable object

Tags: typescript, interface, extending

I would like to extend Mocha's `describe` with `forUsers` function that would create multiple describe. One for each user.

Original description definition:

```
interface IContextDefinition {
    (description: string, callback: (this: ISuiteCallbackContext) => void): ISuite;
    only(description: string, callback: (this: ISuiteCallbackContext) => void): ISuite;
    skip(description: string, callback: (this: ISuiteCallbackContext) => void): void;
    timeout(ms: number): void;
}
```

My extension:

```
declare namespace Mocha {
    interface IContextDefinition {
        forUsers(description: string, users: userType[], callback: (this: ISuiteCallbackContext, user: Cypress.userType) => void): void
        only: {
            (description: string, callback: (this: ISuiteCallbackContext) => void): ISuite
            forUsers(description: string, users: userType[], callback: (this: ISuiteCallbackContext, user: userType) => void): void
        }
        skip: {
            (description: string, callback: (this: ISuiteCallbackContext) => void): ISuite
            forUsers(description: string, users: userType[], callback: (this: ISuiteCallbackContext, user: userType) => void): void
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'only' must be of type '(description: string, callback: (this: ISuiteCallbackContext) => void) => ISuite', but here has type '{ (description: string, callback: (this: ISuiteCallbackContext) => void): ISuite; forUsers(description: string, users: userType[], callback: (this: ISuiteCallbackContext, user: userType) => void): void; }'.
```

That `only`, can be only of type original type, even if the new type includes the old one.

Comment: why are yout trying to overwrite the definition? if you simply define your own definition in your namespace its better i think

Comment: The files are scoped, meaning, variables are not shared unless exported, and since I don't want other to import this function declaring `describe.forUsers` sounded like the best place to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Right, if a property has a hard-coded type (as opposed to an interface that you can augment), you can't change the type.  If you really want to change the type of `only`, rather than redesign your API extension in a way that can be declared via augmentation, then you'll need to fork the Mocha type declarations; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52503107) for the possible ways to do that.