# Universally patching an interface with declaration merging

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

tl;dr - I want to merge an interface from a third party typing with my own, such that anyone importing the original interface will instead get the merged interface.
Is this possible?

---

I'm working on a project written in JavaScript and AngularJS, and we've started switching to TypeScript.
With that, we're using the [AngularJS typings from DefinitelyTyped](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/angular), but we would like to customize it a bit.
For example, we would like to change the `IController` interface such that the definition of `$onInit()?: void` becomes `$onInit(): void` to make it mandatory.

I can achieve this by merging declarations with my own interface:

```
interface IController {
    $onInit(): void;
}
```

But I haven't figured out how to do this in a way that applies the merged interface to all uses of `IController`.
This is important so I can enforce that all controllers have this function, without letting cases slip by, where someone e.g. didn't import the right interface.

Can this be done? And if so, how?

PS: I've tried a bunch of different combinations of namespaces, but I'm not too strong in that area, so maybe I just haven't hit the right incantation yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't merge an optional method with a required one.  (It sounds like so far you haven't actually merged anything but have just declared a separate interface that your code can use instead of the original `IController`.)  You'll have to fork the `@types/angular` typings for your project; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52503107) for a summary of the possible ways of doing that.

Comment: Ah, that explains why it seemed to work then, though I could swear I saw someone doing it elsewhere. I was hoping we wouldn't have to fork it, but c'est la vie I guess. Thanks for the help :)