# How to define custom query helper in mongoose model with typescript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I want to define custom query helper using  [query helper api](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#query-helpers) . 
Here the example:

```
// models/article.ts

import { Document, Schema, Model, model } from 'mongoose';

interface IArticle extends Document {
   name: string;
}

interface IArticleModel extends Model<IArticle> {
   someStaticMethod(): Promise<any>;
}

const ArticleSchema = new Schema( { name: String } )

ArticleSchema.query.byName = function(name) {
    return this.find({ name })
}

export default model<IArticle, IArticleModel>('Article', ArticleSchema);



// routes/article.ts
import ArticleModel from '../models/article.ts'

router.get('/articles, (req, res) => {
    ArticleModel.find().byName('example')
})
```

Typescript complains about `byName` method when I chain it with defaults.
I can put it in `IArticleModel` interface but in that case I could only call it from model.
Where should I put the definition of this method to use it in chainable way?

Comment: Seems like it should be `AnimalInstance.find()` rather than `AnimalSchema.find`

Comment: @ExplosionPills thank you. My mistake I updated the question

Comment: It looks like the `@types/mongoose` declarations need significant changes to support custom query helpers.  I'm working on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've drafted [a new version of `@types/mongoose`](https://github.com/mattmccutchen/DefinitelyTyped/tree/mongoose-query-helpers/types/mongoose) that supports query helpers.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52503107) for ways to install a modified `@types` package.  With my version, you should be able to write the following in `models/article.ts`:

```
import { Document, Schema, Model, model, DocumentQuery } from 'mongoose';

interface IArticle extends Document {
   name: string;
}

interface IArticleModel extends Model<IArticle, typeof articleQueryHelpers> {
   someStaticMethod(): Promise<any>;
}

const ArticleSchema = new Schema( { name: String } )

let articleQueryHelpers = {
    byName(this: DocumentQuery<any, IArticle>, name: string) {
        return this.find({ name });
    }
};
ArticleSchema.query = articleQueryHelpers;

export default model<IArticle, IArticleModel>('Article', ArticleSchema);
```

and then `routes/article.ts` will work.  If this works for you, then I will submit a pull request to the original package on DefinitelyTyped.

Comment: Thanks it works, I actually did my own solution but it is not as elegant as yours.

Comment: OK, here is [the DefinitelyTyped pull request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/29894).

Comment: I think `Promise<any>` should be changed with `MongooseQuery<IArticle>`.
I tried with this solution but I couldn't chain any query helpers after my custom functions (both static and query helper).