# mongoose query helpers in typescript: property does not exist on type Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, typescript-typings

Based on mongoose's [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#query-helpers), I tried to create a chainable `byYear` query helper method as follows:

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { IMovie } from '../interfaces/movies'

export interface MovieDocument extends IMovie, mongoose.Document {}

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Missing ID'],
        index: { unique: true },
    },
    title: { type: String, required: [true, 'Missing title'] },
    year: Number,
    director: String,
    actor: [String],
})

schema.query.byYear = function (year) {
    return this.find({ year: year })
}

export const Movie = mongoose.model<MovieDocument>(
    'Movies',
    schema,
    'Movies'
)
```

where `IMovie` is a simple `interface` having the same fields as the `schema`.

Then I tried using my query helper:

```
Movie.find().byYear(year).then(movies => {
    console.log('found these movies:', movies)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('error:' + err)
})
```

But I get `Property 'byYear' does not exist on type 'Query<MovieDocument[], MovieDocument, {}>'` for the `Movie.find().byYear()` part. Nevertheless, the code seems to work, but it seems that due to insufficient typing VS Code does not realize that the `Query` returned by `Movie.find()` actually *does* have a `byYear` method. How do I do this properly?

---

**UPDATE 2021-05-02:** I should have emphasized more that the code I present *works* beautifully. My problem and the matter of the question is more geared towards how to correctly 'type' this in TypeScript or simply why the error occurs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define custom query helper in mongoose model with typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856264/how-to-define-custom-query-helper-in-mongoose-model-with-typescript)

Comment: Not reallly. When trying exactly what is in the answer to that question, I get `Type '{ byYear(this: mg.DocumentQuery<any, MovieDocument>, year: number): mg.Query<MovieDocument[], MovieDocument, {}>; }' is not assignable to type '{ [name: string]: <T extends any = any>(this: T, ...args: any[]) => any; }'.
  Property 'byYear' is incompatible with index signature.` (this is my signature: `byYear(this: mg.DocumentQuery<any, MovieDocument>, year: number)`). The linked PR was merged in and I have the latest version. May be related: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/23132

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
Movie.find().byYear(year).exec((err, movies) => {
  if (err) {
        console.log('error:' + err)
  } else {
        console.log('found these movies:', movies)
  }
})
```

Basically you should use `.exec` and **not** `.then` method.
You can find more reference here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#query-helpers

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this does not help. I don't see why `.then` should not be used (despite the linked documentation giving an example of usage with `.exec`), but anyway, the error I descibed is about the `byYear` property of the object returned by `find()` not being found. It is irrelevant, what happens after the `.byYear()` call. Additionally, as I said, the code works, it's just an error that VS Code gives me for my code.

Answer (score -2):

You need to export it like below

```
  export interface MovieDocument extends IMovie, mongoose.Document {
    }
    
    const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
        id: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'Missing ID'],
            index: { unique: true },
        },
        title: { type: String, required: [true, 'Missing title'] },
        year: Number,
        director: String,
        actor: [String],
    })
    
    schema.query.byYear = function(year){
        return this.find({ year: year });
    }
    
    const Movie = mongoose.model<MovieDocument>(
        'Movies',
        schema
    );

module.exports = Movie; // this file will i have saved it as movie.ts extension
```

And Access in helper like this **Make Sure to use require while importing, I have tested this and its working fine**

```
const Movie = require('./models/movie'); 

Movie.find().byYear(2020).then((movies: any) => {
    console.log('found these movies:', movies)
}).catch((err: any) => {
    console.log('error:' + err)
})
```

Comment: Have you tested your answer? It seems to make very little sense to me that you are extending the document interface with the `byYear` method that operates on the collection level (should be a method called on the model, not an instance of the model, ie a document). I don't understand how you want to execute a query on a single MovieDocument instance... Furthermore, the documentation clearly shows a very different example usage, which _does_ in fact work (what you present fails with `byYear is not a function` but I think it's logically flawed to begin with).