# Typescript doesn't understand that props are provided by react-navigation withNavigation HOC

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, higher-order-functions

I'm having an issue with

`"react-navigation": "2.18.2",
"@types/react-navigation": "2.13.0",
"typescript": "3.1.6",`

I'm trying to use `withNavigation` HOC in a child component, but that  causes the parent component to say that not all necessary props are passed down. I.e.

In parent:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Child
      someProp={true}
    />
  );
}
```

In child:

```
export interface IChildProps {
  someProp: boolean
}

class Child extends React.Component<IChildProps & NavigationInjectedProps> {
  render() {
    return (<Text>Child component </Text>)
  }
}

export default withNavigation(Child)
```

I get this error in the parent:
`Property 'navigation' is missing in type ...`, indicating that the parent can't seem to figure out that `navigation` is passed to the child through the `withNavigation` HOC for some reason?

I can of course pass down the `navigation` prop from the parent, but that renders `withNavigation` kind of useless, and just moves the problem up the ancestor chain :smiley:

I've looked at the type definitions, and can't find any errors with it. Can someone here perhaps help me clear up what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem if I enable the `strictFunctionTypes` compiler option.  The declaration of `withNavigation` in the `@types/react-navigation` package wasn't designed to work with this option.  I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/30440) to fix it.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52503107) for the possible ways to use my modified declarations until the pull request is merged.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense! :)