# How to set the model type n pouchdb upsert?

Tags: typescript, pouchdb, upsert

It seem I cant find solution on this. using [upsert on pouchdb](https://github.com/pouchdb/upsert) I am getting `TS2345` and or `TS2339`.

I tried using it like htis.

```
db.upsert('id', doc => {
  doc.p = 'sample';
  return doc;
});
```

but on the `doc.p` I am getting `TS2339` `Property 'p' does not exist on type '{} | IdMeta'`

and base on pouchdb-upsert/index.d.ts it has this definition

```
upsert<Model>(docId: Core.DocumentId, diffFun: UpsertDiffCallback<Content & Model>): Promise<UpsertResponse>;
```

So I tried this

```
db.upsert<{ p: string }>('id', doc => {
  doc.p = 'sample';
  return doc;
});
```

but now I am getting `TS2345` and `TS2339`. here is the error

```
Argument of type '(doc: {} | Document<{ p: string; }>) => {} | Document<{ p: string; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UpsertDiffCallback<{ p: string; }>'.
   Type '{} | Document<{ p: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'false | "" | 0 | ({ p: string; } & Partial<IdMeta>) | null | undefined'.
     Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'false | "" | 0 | ({ p: string; } & Partial<IdMeta>) | null | undefined'.
       Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{ p: string; } & Partial<IdMeta>'.
         Type '{}' is not assignable to type '{ p: string; }'.
           Property 'p' is missing in type '{}'. (typescript-tide)
```

Anyone? please, thanks.

**Update**

When I test it like this:

```
  public test() {
    new PouchDB('test').upsert<{ p: string }>('id', doc => {
      doc.p = 'test string';
      return doc;
    })
  }
```

I am getting this:

```
Argument of type '(doc: Partial<Document<{ p: string; }>>) => Partial<Document<{ p: string; }>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UpsertDiffCallback<{ p: string; }>'.
   Type 'Partial<Document<{ p: string;; }>>' is not assignable to type 'false | "" | 0 | ({ p: string; } & Partial<IdMeta>) | null | undefined'.
     Type 'Partial<Document<{ p: string; }>>' is not assignable to type '{ p: string; } & Partial<IdMeta>'.
       Type 'Partial<Document<{ p: string; }>>' is not assignable to type '{ p: string; }'.
         Types of property 'p' are incompatible.
           Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
             Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. (typescript-tide)
```

While if I do it like this:

```
  public test2() {
    new PouchDB<{ p: string }>('test').upsert('id', doc => {
      doc.p = 'test string';
      return doc;
    })
  }
```

I am getting this:

```
Argument of type '(doc: Partial<Document<{ p: string; }>>) => Partial<Document<{ p: string; }>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UpsertDiffCallback<{ p: string; } & Partial<Document<{ p: string; }>>>'.
   Type 'Partial<Document<{ p: string; }>>' is not assignable to type 'false | "" | 0 | ({ p: string; } & Partial<Document<{ p: string; }>> & Partial<IdMeta>) | null | ...'.
     Type 'Partial<Document<{ p: string; }>>' is not assignable to type '{ p: string; } & Partial<Document<{ p: string; }>> & Partial<IdMeta>'.
       Type 'Partial<Document<{ p: string; }>>' is not assignable to type '{ p: string; }'.
         Types of property 'p' are incompatible.
           Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
             Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. (typescript-tide)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem is that your `diffFun` receives the argument `{}` if the document does not exist, and that type does not have any fields.  I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/30494) to DefinitelyTyped to change the argument type to `Partial<Core.Document<Content & Model>>`, which will be more useful since it will allow you to assign to fields.  (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52503107) for the possible ways to use my modified declarations until the pull request is merged.)

However, if you use a document type with required fields such as `{ p: string }`, you still won't be able to return `doc` without a type assertion because TypeScript still thinks that `doc` has only an optional property.  You could specify the document type as `{ p?: string }` and then your code will compile without error.  But if you do expect all documents in the database to have a `p` property, it's probably better practice to use `{ p: string }` and have each `diffFun` either use a type assertion or return a new object, so you're reminded that you need to initialize all required properties in the case that the document didn't exist.

Comment: Thanks! BTW your PR is still not merged, I just patch my index.d.ts but I still got this  ```(doc: Partial<Document<{ p: string; }>>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UpsertDiffCallback<{ p: string; } & void>``` . And if I wont specify the document type, I am getting this ```(doc: Partial<IdMeta>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UpsertDiffCallback<void & {}>```

Comment: Did you remove the `return doc` statement from the `diffFun`?  The function is required to return the new document.  If that wasn't it, please update the question with your latest code so I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry, I didn't add the ```return doc``` but when I did, please see the update above.

Comment: Ah.  This is the issue I mentioned in the second paragraph of the answer.  You'll need to use a type assertion before returning `doc`, for example, `return <{p: string}>doc;`.